# Determining if certain sets are open or closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

I would like someone to verify my answers to the below questions are correct.

Exercise 3.2.8 from `Understanding Analysis` by Stephen Abbott.

> Assume that $A$ is an open set, and $B$ is a closed set. Determine if the following sets are definitely open, definitely closed, both, or neither.

> (a) $\overline{A \cup B}$

> (b) $A-B = \{x \in A: x \notin B\}$

> (c) $(A^C \cup B)^C$

> (d) $(A \cap B) \cup (A^C \cap B)$

> (e) $(\overline{A})^C \cap \overline{A^C}$

***My Attempt***.

(a) $\overline{A}$ is definitely closed for any set $A$. So, $\overline{A \cup B}$ is definitely closed.

(b) $A - B$ is definitely open. For all $x$ remaining in $A - B$, there exists an $\epsilon$-neighbourhood, that is contained entirely in $A - B$.

Consider $A = (0,1)$, $B=\{1/n:n \in \mathbf{N}\} \cup \{0\}$.
$A-B$ is still open, because for the difference set is
\begin{align*}
 \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n+1}\right) 
\end{align*}
which is a countable union of open sets.

(c) $(A^C \cup B)^C$ is definitely open. $A^C$ is closed, so $A^C \cup B$ is closed and therefore $(A^C \cup B)^C$ is open.

(d) $(A \cap B) \cup (A^C \cap B) = (A \cup A^C) \cap B = \mathbb{R} \cap B = B$. This set is definitely closed.

(e) $(\overline{A})^C \cap \overline{A^C}$. I can't tell this one for sure, because its the intersection of an open set with a closed set.

Comment: I think your b) needs more explanation (note $A\setminus B=A\cap B^C$).

Comment: @DavidMitra, can I argue: $A$ is open, $B^C$ is open, so finite intersection is open?

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answers for a)-d) are correct.

For e): Since $A$ is open its complement is closed. So $(\overline {A^{c})}=A^{c}$. Now $(\overline A)^{c} \cap A^{c}=(\overline A)^{c}$ which is open.

Comment: How is $(\overline{A})^C \cap A^C = (\overline{A})^C$? Perhaps, I'm missing something here.

Comment: @Quasar Since $A$ is subset of its closure we see that $(\overline A)^{c}$ is a subset of $A^{c}$. So when  you intersect these two we get $(\overline A)^{c}$

Comment: @Quasar and Kavi Rama Murthy, relevant? https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Complement_of_Closure_is_Regular_Closed https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complement_of_Interior_equals_Closure_of_Complement https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Interior_equals_Complement_of_Closure_of_Complement